# How set intent-filter use Java code?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I write a activity , I want to use click search button jump this activity, I write some code in Manifest.

```
<activity android:theme="@style/launcher" android:name=".Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

It is work. But now I want to people control in in other activity, people can set this activity jump or not jump when long press search button.

Answer (score -2):

please use bellow code.

```
        Intent in =new Intent(ActivityName.this,switcActivty.class);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(intent.getAction());
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        startActivity(in);
```

Comment: sorry replace dialIntent to in.